# How to select user ID who has saved the most products and the list of products he has saved

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query the user ID who has saved the most products and the list of products he has saved

```
+----------------+---------+
| Saved products | user_id |
+----------------+---------+
| A              | 105531  |
| B              | 295014  |
| C              | 104230  |
| D              | 55023   |
| E              | 234510  |
| E              | 105531  |
| ……             | ……      |
| F              | 234510  |
| K              | 2512201 |
| M              | 2253121 |
| O              | 3000451 |
+----------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES [User_ID]
   ,STRING_AGG([Product],',') AS [Product List]
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT([Product])) AS [Products Count]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [User_ID]
ORDER BY [Products Count] DESC
```

[DB_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=77dd8d3fce3fd6ae4dc1cc562a478b9a)

Comment: hi, how to i get the list of products as well?

Comment: which is your DBMS & version ? i.e. SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL

Comment: Microsoft SQL server Management Studio

Comment: @Junmai I've updated the code with a working fiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly one user with the most products (in the event of a tie), then you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t 
where t.user_id = (select t2.user_id
                   from t t2
                   group by t2.user_id
                   order by count(*) desc
                   fetch first 1 row only
                  );
```